# QML, Qt 4.8: How to enable openGl and Chromeless at the same time?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

So here is my main

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Depending on which is the recommended way for the platform, either use
    // opengl graphics system or paint into QGLWidget.
    #ifdef SHADEREFFECTS_USE_OPENGL_GRAPHICSSYSTEM
        QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("opengl");
    #endif

        QApplication a(argc, argv);

    #ifndef SHADEREFFECTS_USE_OPENGL_GRAPHICSSYSTEM
        QGLFormat format = QGLFormat::defaultFormat();
        format.setSampleBuffers(false);
        format.setSwapInterval(1);
        QGLWidget* glWidget = new QGLWidget(format);
        glWidget->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    #endif

        MainWindow w(glWidget);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and files I use to open QML

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
  qmlRegisterType<QGraphicsBlurEffect>("Effects",1,0,"Blur");
  /* turn off window decorations */
  setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);



  ui = new QDeclarativeView;
  ui->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/assets/ui.qml"));

 // ui->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);


  setCentralWidget(ui);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QDeclarativeView *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I try to enable Open GL But I see nothing, when I comment lines in main that in my opinion had to do the job i SEE MY CHROMELESS WINDOW BUT also

```
Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
ShaderEffectItem::paint - OpenGL not available
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same issue, but it doesn't seem to be possible. When the parent window is transparent, OpenGL elements never seem to draw, it looks like OpenGL elements can only be rendered to a visible portion in a window, I haven't tried this yet but it might be possible to work around the issue by painting the main window with an almost fully transparent layer:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  QPainter painter;

  painter.begin(this);
  painter.fillRect(event->rect(), QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 1)));
  painter.end();
}
```

In-theory this *should* provide OpenGL with a visible parent to render onto.

<strike>In your code your calling QWidget->setAttribute multiple times, as this sets a single property, each time you set the property it's overwriting the previous value. You should merge the flags into one call:</strike>

setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground | Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);

Comment: This statement is not correct: `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground | Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);` Look at the .h file, these enum values are not bitmasks and OR operation is illegal.

Comment: Oops, was thinking of setWindowState.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/opengl_and_translucent_background_do_not_work_together_due_to_a_limitation

It seems impossible.